# How to read out partial derivatives

Tags: mathematics

If you have a 2-variable function f(x,y) you can compute its partial derivatives f_x(x,y) and f_y(x,y), but also the mixed partial derivatives f_{xy}(x,y) and f_{yx}(x,y). How do you read these symbols?

Comment: If the "_{x,y}" could alternatively be written as a subscript, it would make sense to me to say it "sub x y".  But I'm just guessing.

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network_MathematicsSE

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth : I'm not sure. Math-stackexchange deals with questions about mathematics (I mean problems/exercises/topics). This is not a question about mathematics. I just want to know how read the symbol.

Comment: The question is likely to be closed here, but it's 'f sub x y of x and y' and 'f sub y x of x and y'. Subscripts are 'sub', functions are 'of', commas are 'and'.

Comment: I'm quite sure. They have a 'pronunciation' tag. Very peripheral registers  are off-topic on ELU. Would you expect a Professor of Linguistics or a Professor of Mathematics to be familiar with this usage?

Comment: Thank you for the advice and for checking their tags. I'll try with Math stack exchange next time. I wasn't aware of the fact that questions about the usage of English in Mathematics were forbidden. I think that you're right, probably a professor of linguistics is not familiar with partial derivatives. I was aware that some users were not going to be able to answer to my question. When I asked this question I was hoping that the users of this website are not only professors of linguistics, but people with different backgrounds (maybe even people that studied/taught mathematics).

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth It seems that this kind of questions are not appreciated on MathStackExchange either. I saw that sometimes they closed questions with the tag "pronunciation" because ""This question is not about mathematics, within the scope defined in the help center."". See e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/233372/correct-english-pronunciation-of-the-word-poset

Comment: I agree with the comment by @jimm101 as shorthand for someone who knows that subscripts correspond to differentiation. More precise phrases are "the derivative with respect to *x* of the function *f* of *x* and *y* and "the second derivative with respect to *x* and *y* of the function *f* of *x* and *y*." One could specify "partial derivative," but that's redundant because it's clear that *f* is a function of multiple variables.

Comment: I'd post it there and complain if _they_ didn't answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This reference might be helpful.
[Wikipedia total derivative](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative)

As your questions suggests, when speaking it isn’t easy to be clear. The written symbols contain information that take more time and effort to express verbally.  The word “derivative” could mean total or partial derivative.

I recommend saying “partial derivative of f with respect to x.”  Many words but unambiguous.

Comment: Your question is answer